# Compare two sheets in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have two excel sheets:

```
-Sheet1 (Giant list)
C2: Application name
D2: Local Name
E2: Description

-Sheet2 (Less application and local names than in sheet2)
A1: Application name
A2: Local name
```

I want to place the description from Sheet1 next to the assigned Local Name in Sheet2.

The problem is that are more local names in Sheet1.

Is there a way to place the description next to the correct local name in Sheet2?

Comment: How do you determine which is the correct local name? How is the Local Name in Sheet2 assigned?

Comment: I like better this method: [How to Use Index Match Instead of Vlookup](https://www.excelcampus.com/functions/index-match-formula/).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can use `Vlookup` function.  Vlookup is an essential function in excel and if you learn it well, you will save yourself lots of time.
Assuming your `localname` is unique, try this formula in your sheet2, to cell where you want to show your description.
`=vlookup([localname in sheet2];[D2:E100];2;false)`

If `localname` is not unique and then you will need to concat it with `application name` to make it unique. Of course you will need to update your formula then accordingly.

Update:
Type this formula into sheet2, c2.  Then copy it and paste to cells below c2.
=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!$D$2:$E$216,2,FALSE)

Comment: Can you let me see how it's done? I've shared it via this link: https://we.tl/t-V62ZogPfVe

Comment: Ozgun's answer helped me but not all descriptions are visible.. How can I concat it with the application name?

Comment: Toon there are values in your sheet2 which do not exist in sheet1.

Comment: Can it be done via the Application name instead of the Local name?

Comment: Did you apply the formula I just typed into the answer field?  ~15% of your data does not exist in sheet1, neither local names nor applicaiton names.   Therefore there is no way to do it for that 15%.

Comment: The rest I can fill in manually it still will take some time but less as before. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Toon consider marking Ozgun's answer as correct if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As harrymc said, you could also try [INDEX/MATCH function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/look-up-values-with-vlookup-index-or-match-68297403-7c3c-4150-9e3c-4d348188976b).
Besides, I also suggest that you use the IFERROR function to display unmatched items as empty values.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!E:E,MATCH(Sheet2!B2,Sheet1!D:D,0)),"")
```

[image]